# Оптимизация подсветки синтаксиса pygments

Tags: python

Нашёл на форуме такой вопрос с ответом на него: [Как сделать подсветку синтаксиса в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141182/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0-%D0%B2-tkinter)

Воспользовался таким же подходом, но сразу увидел неудобства: набор текста очень теперь с фризами.
Удалил часть кода, отвечающую за удаление тегов. Помогло, но не сильно.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему.

Comment: любопытно, а на сколько нагружен процессор ? (на 1 ядре)

Comment: при редактировании текста в ~500 строк идёт в 50%. Задержка при редактировании - ~3 секунды. Проц - i3 3217U

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно просто рабочее решение, используйте модуль [Chlorophyll](https://github.com/rdbende/chlorophyll).

Пример ниже создает и отображает 10000 строк, есть небольшая задержка при вставке текста в контрол, но при прокрутке никаких фризов нет:

```
import tkinter as tk

import pygments.lexers
from chlorophyll import CodeView

root = tk.Tk()

codeview = CodeView(root, lexer=pygments.lexers.PythonLexer, color_scheme="dracula")
codeview.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

codeview.insert("0.0", "\n".join(f"print({i})" for i in range(10000)))

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Скриншот]