# Сама подсветка синтакса, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Ещё раз добрый день. Я пытаюсь сделать подсветку синтакса с помощью библиотеки Pygments.
Проблема заключается в том, что я не могу сделать саму подсветку.
Я читал документацию(не полностью), смотрел разные готовые коды, но не помогало.
Код ниже:

```
# Текстовое поле
class Tab(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root, name):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)

        self.root = root
        self.name = name

        # Текстовое поле
        self.textWidget = CustomText(self, font = "DejaVuSansMono 10", bg = "#fff")
        # Панель с номерами строк
        linenumbers = TextLineNumbers(self, width=30)
        linenumbers.attach(self.textWidget)
        
        def on_change(event):
            linenumbers.redraw()
        
        self.textWidget.bind("<<Change>>", on_change)
        self.textWidget.bind("<Configure>", on_change)
        # ---
        self.textWidget.tag_configure("Token.Keyword", fg="red")
        # ---
        vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.textWidget.yview)
        self.textWidget.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        
        linenumbers.pack(side="left", fill="y")
        vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.textWidget.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        # Сохранение файла
    def saveas(self, event=None):
        file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=FILE_TYPES,
                                            defaultextension=FILE_TYPES[0][1])
        if file != "":
            self.file_name = file
            self.save(file)

    def save(self, event=None):
        if self.file_name is None:
            self.saveas()
        else:
            self._save(self.file_name)

    def save_tab(self, event=None):
        file = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes=FILE_TYPES,
                                            defaultextension=FILE_TYPES[0][1])
        if file != "":
            self.file_name = file
            self.save(file)

    def _save(self, filename):
        textWidget = self.textWidget.get("0.0", "end")
        with open(filename, "w") as file:
            file.write(textWidget)
            self.saved_text = textWidget.rstrip()

        # Тестовый синтакс
    def syn(self, event=None):
        self.textWidget.mark_set("range_start", "1.0")
        data = self.textWidget.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        for token, content in lex(data, PythonLexer()):
            self.textWidget.mark_set("range_end", "range_start + %dc" % len(content))
            self.textWidget.tag_add(str(token), "range_start", "range_end")
            self.textWidget.mark_set("range_start", "range_end")

        root.bind("<Key>", self.syn)
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать подсветку синтаксиса в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141182/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%b2-tkinter)

Comment: я не могу вообще подсветить синтакс :(

Comment: что значит 'не могу' ? посмотрите в той теме в ответе внизу  рабочий код

Comment: Что такое CustomText и TextLineNumbers?