# Как изменить цвет комментария в тексте кода на python, находящемся в виджете ScrolledText?

Tags: python, tkinter

[image: как это сделано в саблайм]

выше я привел пример кода в sublime text 3. в нем текст комментария серый. что добавить в словарь ниже, чтобы изменить текст комментария в виджете? (используется библиотека pygments)
[image]

Comment: Похоже, что вы брали код из этого ответа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141225/1365 Там есть отладочный вывод в консоль, где можно посмотреть, какой тип токена выдается на комментарии

Comment: Я дополнил в ответе по ссылке, как добавлять подсветку нужных токенов.