# Python. Подсвечивание вводимого текста в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Здрасте! Я делаю редактор кода для проекта на tkinter. Есть ли возможность сделать автоматическую замену цвета у определённых слов? Например, чтобы слово red - подсвечиволось крвсным, а blue - синим.

Comment: В текстовом виджете можно. В нём у текста есть теги и у них атрибуты. Например, определить тег "синий" и помечать им нужные слова при редактировании.

Comment: @GrAnd, cпасибо за подсказку, но можете, пожалуйста, для ясности привести пример того, как надо указывать тэг и атрибуты? Просто для выделения цветом какого-то определённого слова. Извините, если сильно туплю.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как сделать подсветку синтаксиса в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1141182/1365)

Comment: @insolor Спасибо огромное)