# Как подсвечивать разными цветами текст в виджете text tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Нужно причём чтобы подсвечивались слова которые написал пользователь. К примеру : написал "банан" написанная надпись "банан" начала подсвечиваться жёлтым, написал "яблоко"  подвешивается красным. Как это реализовать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786507/how-to-change-the-color-of-certain-words-in-the-tkinter-text-widget

Comment: Где именно вы хотите подсвечивать текст?

Comment: Можете посмотреть [проект](https://github.com/wchistow/EPL). В файле `interface.py` реализована подсветка текста.

Comment: @КостяКилиманов в виджете text

Comment: @splash58. Хороший пример, но только как это сделать не выделяя текст. А просто если в тексте найдено слово "яблоко" то покрасить его в красный?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Алгоритм такой:

В текстовом поле нужно создать тег - объект, для которого можно указать какие-то свойства (фон, цвет текста, другие свойства шрифта) или, например, назначить реакцию на событие (например, при клике мышью выполнить какое-то действие). Это выполняется через метод текстового поля `tag_config`.

Дальше этот тег нужно назначить на фрагмент текста, тогда этот фрагмент текста получит свойства, прописанные для этого тега. Это делается через метод `tag_add`.

Дальше, если нужно подсвечивать по мере ввода, то нужно при каждом изменении текста нужно разбивать его на отдельные слова, каждое слово проверять - нужно его красить или нет, нужным словам назначить соответствующий тег.

Пример кода на основе ответа: [Как сделать подсветку синтаксиса в tkinter](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1141225/1365)

Код упрощаем, заменяем разбиение на токены через pygments на выделение слов по простому регулярному выражению, словам через словарь сопоставляем типы тегов.

По мере ввода текст подсвечиваем.

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root)
text.pack()

# Создаем теги с разными свойствами, которые будем присваивать соответствующим частям текста
text.tag_config("blue", foreground="blue")
text.tag_config("red", foreground="red")
text.tag_config("yellow", foreground="yellow")

# Прописываем соответствие тексту название тега подсветки (из прописанных выше)
token_to_tag = {
    "банан": "yellow",
    "яблоко": "red",
}


def on_edit(event):
    # Удалить все имеющиеся теги из текста
    for tag in text.tag_names():
        text.tag_remove(tag, 1.0, tk.END)
    
    # Разобрать текст на токены
    s = text.get(1.0, tk.END)
    
    for i, line in enumerate(s.splitlines(), start=1):  # Идем по тексту построчно, считаем номер строки (от 1)
        for match in re.finditer(r"\w+", line):  # Находим в тексте отдельные слова
            token_text = match.group(0).lower()  # lower - чтобы срабатывало, и на банан, и на БаНаН
            start = match.start()
            end = match.end()
            print(start, end, token_text)  # Отладочный вывод
            
            if token_text in token_to_tag:
                # Если слово есть в словаре token_to_tag, добавляем ему тег с нужным цветом из этого словаря
                # Координаты начала-окончания диапазон текста задаются через "номер_строки.индекс_символа"
                text.tag_add(token_to_tag[token_text], f"{i}.{start}", f"{i}.{end}")

    # Сбросить флаг редактирования текста
    text.edit_modified(0)


text.bind('<<Modified>>', on_edit)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!